# why this is not overloading?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have two methods as follows

```
public void add(List<String> strs) {...}

public void add(List<Integer> ints) {...}
```

I get compilation errors, so my question is why this is not overloading, and what is the advantage of using generics then?

This is the error that I get:

```
Method add(List<Integer>) has the same erasure add(List<E>) as another method in type Child
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Java Generics are a compile-time only language feature; the generic types (such as `String` and `Integer` here) are *erased* during the compilation, and the bytecode only includes the raw type, like this:

```
public void add(List strs) {...}
```

Because of this, you can't have multiple methods whose signatures differ only in the generic types. There are a few ways around this, including varargs and making your method itself generic, and the best approach depends on the specific task.

The advantage of generics is that inside a method that takes a `List<String>`, you can add or remove elements from the `List` and treat them as just `String` objects, without having to add explicit casting everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Generic types are erased at runtime. SO your `public void add(List<String> strs)` and `public void add(List<Integer> ints){...........}` are the same type , the compiler just places compile-time restrictions on what you can do with them.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile some code against a generic type or method, the compiler works out what you really mean (i.e. what the type argument for T is) and verifies at compile time that you're doing the right thing, but the emitted code again just talks in terms of j`ava.lang.Object` - the compiler generates extra casts where necessary. At execution time, a `List<Integer>` and a `List<String>` are exactly the same; the extra type information has been erased by the compiler.

Thus you get compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` you can do this(overloading) as follows with parameter list contains with `List`.

```
 public void add(List strs){

 }
```

If you use deferent type of `List` with same method name, it will consider as same method.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that the JVM will not decide which method to call at runtime. As opposed to virtual methods / method overriding resolution of overloaded methods are done at compile time. The Java Tutorials on [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) even points out that "Overloaded methods should be used sparingly...".